# what's the proper way to define a default child|route|page in nuxtjs?

Tags: nuxt.js

I was wondering what's the correct way to do this?
so we have  something like  this inside our `pages` folder :

```
product/
       |
        comments.vue
        review.vue
        index.vue
        details.vue
index.vue //root of website
product.vue
```

we have `<nuxt-child />` inside `product.vue` so the `product/index.vue` is the default `child|view|component` of the product and if it doesn't exist, one of the others will be the default child component.
how we can control it when there is no index.vue ?
I tried putting `<details />` inside `index.vue`(for making `details.vue` the `default child`) it's working but is this a correct way to do this? or we should modify the router inside `nuxt.config.js`?

thank you ❤️

Answer (score 1):

Opinion-based questions are forbidden on stackoverflow.

---

I'm not sure how `index.vue` can be confusing but your index page should stay `index.vue` if it's fine semantically and logical. Try not to defeat logic for "more flexible code" purposes or alike.

Don't over-engineer here, if you want to have a `/details` path, just go with it. If you meant something like

```
/pages
-- details
---- index.vue
---- _slug.vue
-- reviews
---- index.vue
---- _slug.vue
```

The pages are nested and your code editor/IDE should help you on this one. Otherwise, you can always have some kind of `reviews/reviews-index.vue` structure but you'll need to overwrite the path if you go this way.

I do recommend using `router-extras` that you can find here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/file-system-routing#extending-the-router
Other approaches are also possible, but I'd rather keep things organized in a Nuxt way and do not write too much homemade router, especially if it's not needed.

---

This is what I mean by code editor help. I can see all of my directories and and `index.vue` in each of them. Type `combiin` (`commuting-billing-index`) if you want to reach `commuting/billing/index`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, my bad im new and i didn't think about opinion-based thing.

Comment: what i had in mind was having a nuxt-child in a parent with some child components and how to go with default child .you know if i dont create product/index.vue one of children will be default child right ?

Comment: @MeysamRahnama I don't understand what you mean, sorry. Can you please give a better example?

Comment: sorry, I just confused you and myself 